# Is there an easy way to integrate jshint with netbeans?

Tags: javascript, netbeans, integration, jshint

Searched the net for a jshint plugin for netbeans, but found none...

Can anyone describe or show an easy solution for jshint integration in netbeans?

Comment: If you want to torture yourself there is the jslint plug-in http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/40893/jslint :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no good plugin for netbeans. Install node, use [grunt](http://gruntjs.com) and start rocking! :)

Comment: I'll upvote you if you can tell me how to connect NetBeans to a grunt task ... :)  Eclipse was so much easier!

Comment: You can just install grunt on windows or linux and use grunt watch to watch a group of files. Grunt will then lint them automatically if you saved your files in netbeans. You can't really connect netbeans to grunt :)

Comment: That's perfect - exactly what I needed to hear :)

Answer (score 4):

I think this may work for you: [jshint](https://github.com/LaurentGoderre/netbeans-jshint)

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans has two plugins for Javascript code quality.

> **[JSHist](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/52226/jshint)**:
>   It is relatively new, It was added on Dic-2013
>   Only supports version 7.4 of Netbeans

and

> **[JSLint](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/40893/jslint)**:
>    It seems that is working as plugin since a while, It was added on Nov-2011 and the last updated was on Oct-2013.
>   Supports versions 7.4, 7.3, 7.2, 7.0 of Netbeans.

It looks like both can be installed manually for version 8.0

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add [this](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/40893/jslint)  plug-in. Supports the Netbeans 7.3.

You can [fork it](https://github.com/lomatek/netbeans-jslint) and add JSHint.