# How to integrate GruntJS with Netbeans 7.3?

Tags: netbeans, less, gruntjs

How do I integrate Grunt into Netbeans 7.3, or alternatively allow Netbeans define some external script/program to exec as part of a build.

This is so I can setup Netbeans to compile Less into CSS automatically.

Comment: [Some](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11467063/1183010) suggest using grunt watch to do the job. But it would be nice having ant-like integration for grunt. I am also searching for an integration where one can call grunt tasks in the same way we now call ant tasks.

Comment: Netbeans 7.4 will handle LESS and SCSS directly.

Comment: netbeans 7.4 is out now, SASS & LESS is available http://wiki.netbeans.org/EaselPlanning

Comment: Still a valid question, integration between NetBeans and JavaScript build tools is still confusing IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to change anything in Netbeans.

You should only use the Grunt to compile LESS into CSS, minify your scripts, etc.

Grunt will run in the background and will compile your LESS files into CSS files whenever you make any changes in this files.

1. Install Node.js (Grunt is running on node.js)
   https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/
2. Install Grunt
   http://gruntjs.com/getting-started
3. On grunt webpage go to plugins subpage and install:

   - grunt-contrib-watch
   - grunt-contrib-less

On each plugins subpage you have exact instructions how to set them up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use java to convert from less to css.Or why do you need configuration in NetBeans?You can create a grunt task,call it with terminal,and task will convert what you need.